# Ins Azure DevOps boards; tasks dedicated to one userstory

Tags: azure-devops

It's possible to drag and drop a task from one userstory to another userstory in Azure DevOps Boards. Is it possible to prefent this?

I expect that a task stays in the original Userstory it's made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can prevent the task from being dragged and dropped from one user story to another by setting permissions. But permissions can only be used for the whole work item, not only for changing links(Task is linked to userstory as child related work). This means that although drag and drop can be prevented, other fields of the work item cannot be modified.

When you don't want the tasks to be dragged, you can set `edit work items in this node` permission to Deny. **Note**: Make sure the work item is in the area you set, and the permission will take effect.

Project Settings -> Boards Project configuration -> Areas -> '**...**' -> Security :
[image]

When you need to modify the work item, you need to open the permission again. This may be a bit of a hassle, but I cannot think of any other better way at the moment.